# Formula dragging query

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to drag a formula from a range to its next immediate column with the following code

```
Range(Cells(11, lc2), Cells(70, lc2)).AutoFill _
Destination:=Range(Cells(11, lc2 + 1), Cells(70, lc2 + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I am facing 1004 error

Please advise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column you are using, `lc2`,  has to be included in the destination e.g.

```
Range(Cells(11, lc2), Cells(70, lc2)).AutoFill _
Destination:=Range(Cells(11, lc2), Cells(70, lc2 + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Meaning you cannot autofill just using column `lc2+1`

Comment: @sachin if this answer helped you resolve your issue, please accept it by clicking the green V on the left